# CUDA Vector Reduction to handle vectors of length less than 512?

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu

I'm working on parallel vector_reduction algorithm tutorial from NVIDIA to implement the algorithm using CUDA C++ API. I have implemented the algorithm but it only works for vector lengths that are fixed to 512. I am not able to figure out how to get it working for vectors less than 512? I want it to work for arbitrary sizes, i.e, 324, 123, 23.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NUM_ELEMENTS 512

__global__ void reduction(float *g_data, int n)
{
    __shared__ float partialSum[NUM_ELEMENTS];

    int tx = threadIdx.x;
    int i = tx + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

    if (i < n) {
        partialSum[tx] = g_data[i];
    }

    int stride;
    for (stride = blockDim.x/2; stride > 0;  stride >>= 1) {
        __syncthreads();
        if (tx < stride) {
           partialSum[tx] += partialSum[tx + stride];
        }
    }

    if (tx == 0) {
        g_data[blockIdx.x] = partialSum[tx];
    }
}

float computeOnDevice(float* h_data, int num_elements)
{
    float* d_data = NULL;
    float result;

    // Memory allocation on device side
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_data, sizeof(float)*num_elements);

    // Copy from host memory to device memory
    cudaMemcpy(d_data, h_data, num_elements * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );

    dim3 blockSize, gridSize;

    // Number of threads in each thread block
    blockSize = dim3(num_elements, 1, 1);

    // Number of thread blocks in grid
    gridSize = dim3(1, 1, 1);

    // Invoke the kernel
    reduction<<<gridSize, blockSize>>>(d_data, num_elements);

    // Copy from device memory back to host memory
    cudaMemcpy(&result, d_data, sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaFree(d_data);
    cudaDeviceReset();
    return result;
}

int main() {

    float *data = new float[NUM_ELEMENTS];
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ELEMENTS; i++) data[i] = 1;
    float r = computeOnDevice(data, NUM_ELEMENTS);
    printf(" result = %f\n" , r);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is 100% correct. The problem is that your bitshifts don't account for the last part of your array. You can easily fix this by artificially extending the array to the next power of 2. This way your entire array will be reduced and the extra "elements" (they don't actually exist) are just ignored.

```
#include <math.h>

__global__ void reduction(float *g_data, int n){
    // figure out exponent of next larger power of 2
    int exponent = ceilf(log2f(n));
    // calculate next larger power of 2
    int size = (int)powf(2, exponent);
    __shared__ float partialSum[NUM_ELEMENTS];

    int tx = threadIdx.x;
    int i = tx + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

    if (i < n){
        partialSum[tx] = g_data[i];
    }

    for (int stride = size / 2; stride > 0; stride >>= 1){
        __syncthreads();

        if (tx < stride) {
            // all threads that run out of bounds do nothing
            // equivalent to adding 0
            if((tx + stride) < n)
                partialSum[tx] += partialSum[tx + stride];
        }
    }

    if (tx == 0){
        g_data[blockIdx.x] = partialSum[tx];
    }
}
```

**Edit**

Regarding your comment, this method of reduction will never work for an array that is being reduced in multiple blocks. So, for compute capability 1.0-1.3, the largest array you can reduce is 512 elements, for compute capability >1.3 you can do up to 1024 elements, this is the maximum number of threads per block.

This is because `__shared__` memory is **shared among threads not blocks**. So, to reduce an array scattered over multiple blocks you'd need to partition the array such that each block reduces a chunk and then leverage `__global__` memory to reduce the values from all blocks. However, `__global__` memory is approximately 10-20 times slower than the (on-chip) `__shared__` memory, so once you start using a lot of blocks, this will become very inefficient.

The alternative would be to have each thread process multiple indices, however, eventually your `partialSum` array won't fit into shared memory anymore and overflow into global memory anyway. This approach would also mean you can never use more than 512 (or 1024) threads, which defeats the purpose of using CUDA which depends on running a very large number of threads to hide latency and make the expensive memory transfer from host to device worth it.

Comment: What about for large arrays where the size is much greater than 512?